Can supersonic flow be achieved without converging diverging nozzle?
Can supersonic flow be achieved without the presence of a converging diverging nozzle if sufficient pressure difference is available?
https://www.tomshardware.com/desktops/pc-building/an-ordinary-squirt-of-canned-air-achieves-supersonic-speeds-engineer-spots-telltale-shock-diamonds
The article above mentions that 'shock diamonds' can be seen out of a flow coming out of compressed air can at 70 PSI. I am assuming that the flow must have reached supersonic for the shock diamonds to occur.

why would the existence of airstream pressure variations require supersonic air speed?

what is the diameter of the nozzle? have you calculated the velocity?

Might explosions answer your question?

@jsotola Are the shock diamonds not created due to supersonic flow? Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond. Please elaborate your explanation a little bit

@Solar Mike Calculating the velocity using Bernoulli's equation certainly gives a very high velocity (definitely supersonic). However, I am assuming that compressibility effects will be high enough for directly using Bernoulli's equation. Energy conservation also gives a very high velocity (neglecting friction)

@Sami Safarani Isn't explosion shock wave caused by the gases expanding faster than sonic speed? Please elaborate your answer a little.

@Johnsmith the pictures in the link may have been obtained by using a polarizing filter in the setup, which would reveal the density variations in the stream of any speed ... I do not know if diamond shaped density variations can only be produced in supersonic air flow, but I question everything seen on the internet

Yes. Supersonic flow can be achieved without the presence of a converging-diverging nozzle. You just need an orifice to get the air to escape from a high-pressure vessel.
Assume the total pressure of the flow through the duct is P0, the exit pressure is Pe, and the ambient pressure is Pa.
Simply, You need P0/Pa > 1.893 to get a supersonic flow. So, If your vehicle tire gets punctured, you will get supersonic flow since you have enough pressure inside the tire at the beginning. The punctured tire in most of the scenarios gives under expanded flow pattern.
Once the condition P0/Pe is met, the conditions of Pe < Pa or Pe < Pa will decide whether the flow will be under-expanded or over-expanded. This is where you need a convergent/divergent nozzle.
Note: Since it is supersonic, we need to use isentropic relations unless external heat is added/removed and no work is extracted from the flow.
Hope this helps, let me know for more clarity!

Sorry for the late reply...How can the velocity reach supersonic without a properly designed CD nozzle? In compressible flow, I read that no matter how much you increase the pressure ratio, the velocity will get choked, and will go supersonic only in a properly designed CD nozzle. Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Achieving supersonic flow is possible without converging diverging duct (eg. a supersonic aircraft). What I intended to ask was that is it possible to achieve supersonic speed in a duct without presence of a properly designed converging diverging nozzle, as is the case in the compressed air nozzle? From what I could gather, it is not possible to achieve supersonic speeds in a closed duct without a CD nozzle.

Hi @Johnsmith, Yes, In a close duct, not yet exposed to the atmosphere/reservoir, you could only achieve by C-D Nozzle. " I read that no matter how much you increase the pressure ratio, the velocity will get choked" This is the scenario in closed ducts.
But in a ballon, pressurized tank/tube, and compressed container in space, all can produce a supersonic flow without having a CD nozzle.  In these cases only the pressure ratio is critical.
